# How to update data cells in different time periods depending on selected period without Macros?

Tags: excel, vlookup

I am working on scenarios that are time sensitive.

The Base table contains the values for Products A-D from Jan to Dec.

The Improvement table contains the values that will result upon a project being executed, for example Product A performance will initially drop to 4, then increase back to 5, 6, 6 and will stay at 6 until Dec.

The timing of change is dictated by the third table that shows Product and expected starting period, so in this example Product A will change in April, etc.

The Expected Output table is updated for the periods of improvement (yellow color) and need to keep the latest value (orange color)

[image: Example]

Unfortunately due to IT policies, can't use Macros to solve this problem. I tried using VLOOKUP table, but can't figure out how to update base on a changing month. Appreciate any guidance.